# What is happening during the gap in Application insights Request Telemetry?

Tags: c#, performance, azure-application-insights

I have a the following request in Application insights.

[image: Screenshot of the issue]

How I understand it is that total request time took 422.1ms to complete. During this time a dependent request, the striped blue bar, took 151.1ms. What is happening during the other 271ms, the red part?

The code is as simple as:

```cs
public async Task<Foo> Get()
{
    return await _externalAPI.GetFooExternally()
}
```

Our first thought was it was related to network/framework, but there are other places we are seeing that the gap/delay completely disappears.

Comment: This just means that it took 422 ms to process incoming request and 151 ms out of them were for an outgoing call. It can be because of many things - from some other (non-HTTP) calls which Application Insights doesn't auto-capture to your app being overloaded (potentially for a very short period of time) or even some other process consuming all CPU and your app not getting any. Or, of course, there is some code which actually performs something computationally expensive. Taking profile trace might be a good next step.